# JAXB: How to use auto-generated classes from Spring?

Tags: java, spring, collections, jaxb, xjc

I am using `xjc` to generated Java classes from an `XSD`. The resulting classes only include getter methods for collection types, e.g. `List`, but no setter methods. How can i use these generated classes as beans within the `Spring Framework`, i.e. how to populate these fields with data from *applicationContext.xml*?

As a reply to 'duffymo' and 'fatih': Actually i can tell Spring to use the `JAXB` `ObjectFactory` and its factory methods to create the beans,

```
<bean id="myFactory" class="generated.ObjectFactory" />
<bean id="myBean" factory-bean="myFactory" factory-method="createMyBeanMethod" />
```

the remaining problem is how to populate the collection fields without having setter methods?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can, because they were created under JAXB's control and not the Spring bean factory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the field instead of the getter/setter.

Answer (score 0):

As the generated code is under JAXB's control you wont be able to do that. However, a workaround maybe:

Say JAXB creates a Person class for you, generated properties will be protected.

You can create new class MyPerson extending the Person class and place the setter method inside of MyPerson class. So you can init the property from bean config file and the generated code wont override your changes. It may or may not be a suitable workaround for your case as I dont know the details.

```
     generated :
     public class Person{
          protected List<Something> somethingList;
          .
          .
     }




     class MyPerson extends Person{
         public void setList(List<Something> somethingList){
             this.somethingList= somethingList;
         }

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an extension to generate set methods for lists as indicated here:

- [http://www.java.net/forum/topic/glassfish/metro-and-jaxb/xjc-generate-set-methods-lists-0](http://home.java.net/node/673500)<sup><sup>(redirected)</sup></sup>

Although the given link appears to be broken as the referenced site has been re-organized.

- https://jaxb2-commons.dev.java.net/collection-setter-injector/<sup><sup>(dead link)</sup></sup>

It would be worth posting a question to java.net to get the location of the collection-setter-injector.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of populate your `xjc-generated` beans in applicationContext.xml, you can use [Java-based configuration](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java) for those beans.